# Running Powershell With PHP On IIS

Tags: php, powershell, iis, outlook, fastcgi

**PHP CODE -:**

```
<?php

    $user = "email@outlook.com";

    $script = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\shell_script\\sc.ps1";

    $query = shell_exec("powershell -command $script <nul");
     if($query)
{
   echo "Successful" ;
}
else
   echo "Failed";
}
?>
```

**POWERSHELL CODE -:**

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)

$Mail.To = "email2@outlook.com"
$Mail.Subject = "New Leave Request"
$Mail.Body ="
Dear,

This email contains the body of Email"

$Mail.Send()
```

I have Powershell installed on my laptop with Windows Server 2012 on Windows 8.

I have a website hosted on Windows Server 2012 IIS

When i run the powershell script sc.ps1 on command line on server by command ./sc.ps1 the mail is sent to Outlook.

But when i run the php page in which i have the shell_exec command the mail is not triggered to the outlook and returns page with message Successful as written in PHP Code.
All the work is done on Windows Server 2012

**Running powershell script on command line sends mail but when running script via powershell doesn't trigger the mail and returns successful only as the shell-exec query is running.**

I have done set-ExecutionPolicy as unrestricted .

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757?wa=wsignin1.0) article in MSDN.

As a workaround you may use a low-level API - Extended MAPI which supports such scenarious, or just any other third-party wrapper around that API (for example, Redemption).

Comment: i am able to use the script on localhost. It works perfectly on localhost but this script of powershell doesnt trigger email when used on server

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to pass the execution policy within your `shell_exec`:

```
shell_exec("powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted -command $script <nul");
```

If this doesn't work, you should check the identity of your application pool.

Comment: i used execution policy method but i did not help.

Comment: And can you elaborate more on the thing that what i should do with identity of the app pool

Comment: You could try to set the identity of your app pool to your account and check whether it works. See http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Comment: it didn't work. Any other thing that i can do. I am on the last stage of my project going live

Comment: Did your set the application pool of your website to your user account identity?

Comment: go to this. I am getting a new error.
Check here please -:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668968/unable-to-send-powershell-email-using-php-script-to-outlook-using-iis-windows-se